# Artifacts are not downloaded from nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus

I have been successful in uploading SNAPSHOT jar into Nexus. These are uploaded as timestamp being appended to the jar name. I have given the project.version = "SNAPSHOT" in my build.gradle.

when I am trying to download the same artifacts, it fails saying that -SNAPSHOT is not found, which is logical because the jars are uploaded as _timestamp.

how do I download SNAPSHOT artifacts?

Comment: was my answer useful?

Comment: where do want to download them, i mean do u intend to download as a dependency for a project?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather add SNAPSHOT instead of timestamp - there might be multiple artifacts with same SNAPSHOT version - and resolve the artifacts via appropriate strategy.

See the code below:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. Had to specify the project.version as _SNAPSHOT(e.g 1.0_SNAPSHOT) not bare SNAPSHOT.